# How can I get the details of last schedulable job and of which class? Is there any way?

Tags: apex, soql, scheduled-apex, asynchronous, jobs

I have a requiurement where I have to get the details of last job details and the Of which clas s. How can I get the details ?
i have tried using CronJob details and CronTrigger?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Query for the AsyncApexJob Object.  Something like this will get you started

```
AsyncApexJob myJob = [SELECT Id, Status, ApexClass.Name,
                      FROM AsyncApexJob 
                      Order by CompletedDate DESC limit 1];
```